# A small question about a custom react modal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a modal component by reactjs, it's composed of modal mask and modal body. now i wanna click the modal mask the whole modal component hidden.

Tried add click event on modal mask dom

```
class Modal extends React.Component {

  onClose = () => {
    console.log('close')
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="mocal-mask" onClick={this.onClose}>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-body">
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```css
.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.modal-body {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: none;
}
```

`onClick` function should be console 'close'

Comment: https://codepen.io/WUSO01/pen/arxWZd?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a function `this.onClose` to `onClick` event but you have named your function as `onClick`, you need to define a function named `onClose`

```
onClose = () => {
    console.log('close')
}
```

You can basically handle this in two way

1. From parent component

   ```
   handleClose = () => {
     this.setState({modal: false})
   }

   //  in render 

   { this.state.modal && <Modal onClose={this.handleClose}>}
   ```
2. You can do it in modal itself

   ```
   handleClose = () => {
     this.setState({modal: false})
   }

   // in render 

    return (
       this.state.modal ? <div>...<div> : ''
   )
   ```

Comment: Sry misspelling